# Unconfirmed/Pending Blockchain.info Transactions Returned to Wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions

On 10-26-17, I sent $425 from my blockchain.info wallet to my Coinbase wallet.  As of 10-28-17, the transaction is still pending.  If the transaction is never confirmed, will the $425 reappear in my blockchain.info wallet?

Comment: My Blockchain wallet that is . . .

Answer (score 1):

The transaction was finally confirmed 56 hours after I initiated it.  I assumed the transaction would be rejected, and the funds would revert back to my BlockChain wallet, but they found their way to my Coinbase wallet.

Interestingly, there was no record of the transaction on Coinbase.  After 24 hours, the network had no record of the transaction.  Anyone viewing my Coinbase wallet would have no idea how the funds arrived in the wallet.  All's well that ends well!